# How to set up pom.xml for RichFaces 4.5.17.kcc5 and Primefaces 7.0.RC3 working together on the JSF 2.3 project

Tags: maven, jsf, primefaces, richfaces

Originally my project is set up for RichFaces 4.5.17.kcc5 and it works fine.
After I added the PrimeFace 7.0.RC3 library to the project, my build stop installing (mvn clean install) and I start getting the errors in the log:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:34 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-21T13:55:53+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 73M/1206M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.richfaces:richfaces-resource-optimizer-maven-plugin:4.5.17.kcc5:process (packed-resources) on project uifaces-resources: Exception caught when scanning class org.primefaces.component.schedule.Schedule:
[ERROR] collection: [primefaces:schedule/schedule.css, primefaces:components.css, primefaces:moment/moment.js, primefaces:jquery/jquery.js, primefaces:jquery/jquery-plugins.js, primefaces:core.js, primefaces:components.js, primefaces:schedule/schedule.js]
[ERROR] PartialOrder[primefaces:jquery/jquery.js, primefaces:core.js, primefaces:components.js, primefaces:moment/moment.js, primefaces:chartjs/chartjs.js]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

It happens during the execution this step:

> org.richfaces:richfaces-resource-optimizer-maven-plugin
> (packed-resources)

```
<!-- Packed -->
<execution>
    <id>packed-resources</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <pack>packed</pack>
        <compress>false</compress>
        <resourcesOutputDir>
            ${faces.resources.dir}/org.richfaces.staticResource/${version.org.richfaces}/Packed/
        </resourcesOutputDir>
        <staticResourceMappingFile>
            ${resource.mappings.dir}/optimizedResourcesMapping/Packed.properties
        </staticResourceMappingFile>
        <staticResourcePrefix>org.richfaces.staticResource/${version.org.richfaces}/Packed/
        </staticResourcePrefix>
        <excludedFiles>
            <exclude>^javax.faces</exclude>
            <exclude>^jquery.js$</exclude>
            <exclude>^jquery.*.js$</exclude>
            <exclude>^flot</exclude>
            <exclude>^net.my.uifaces\:css/page.*</exclude>
            <exclude>^net.my.uifaces\:css/button.css</exclude>
            <exclude>^net.my.uifaces\:script/page.*</exclude>
            <exclude>^net.my.uifaces\:script/jquery.*</exclude>
            <exclude>^net.my.uifaces\:theme.*</exclude>
            <exclude>^\Qorg.richfaces.renderkit.html.images.\E.*</exclude>
            <exclude>^\Qorg.richfaces.renderkit.html.iconimages.\E.*</exclude>
            <exclude>^\Qorg.richfaces.ckeditor\E</exclude>
            <exclude>^\Qorg.richfaces.staticResource\E</exclude>
            <exclude>^org\.richfaces:jquery\.js$</exclude>
        </excludedFiles>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Maybe someone has seen this error before. Any guess how to avoid it?

Comment: This might be difficult to untangle so I would disable your "optimizer" and just try and get the app working without the optimizer first.

Comment: @BalusC PrimeFace can be 8 it is not the problem. I just start with this one. I have tried "^primefaces" it does not work.